# How do I populate value to second input field based on a onchange event on a 'select' input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking to duplicate the value of a select input into a second input field using Javascript. I tried to do this using an onchange event call. What should the js code be in order to populate the input field id ='sort' upon change in the select function?

Here is my code

```
<input id = "sort">
<select name="sort_select" onchange="document.getElementById('sort').value = ('#sort_select').val();">
  <option value="Ascending"> Ascending</option>
  <option value="Descending"> Descending</option>
</select>
```

This does not work. I see the error lies in value assignment (('#sort_select').val();)What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS solution: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/2WSfS/)
change this:

```
<select name="sort_select" onchange="document.getElementById('sort').value = ('#sort_select').val();">
```

to

```
<select name="sort_select" onchange="document.getElementById('sort').value = this.value;">
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
$("select").change(function(){
 $("#sort").val($(this).val());

});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wnGJM/2/)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/5S7mh/

```
onChange="document.getElementById('sort').value = (this.options[this.selectedIndex]).value;"
```

Don't use that big ugly line as inline JS though.
Also, start with populating the input box.